# How to make a specific model in Laravel/Lumen according to JSON received from mobile app?

Tags: php, json, kotlin, model, lumen

I am building a web app (with Lumen) which will receive JSON data from a mobile app and store it. And it will also send data in the same JSON format. I have made the model of the data in the mobile app in Kotlin. Which will be serialized to JSON by the retrofit library.

```
data class Mouse(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)
data class Occasion(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)
data class Location(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)
data class Session(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)
data class Project(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)

data class LocOccLMouse(
   val loc: Location,
   val occ: Occasion,
   val lisMouse: List<Mouse>
)

data class SesLOLM(
   val ses: Session,
   val lisLOLM: List<LocOccLMouse>
)

data class SyncClass(
   val prj: Project,
   val lisSesLOLM: List<SesLOLM>
)
```

So I will be sending just the SyncClass from mobile app.

But I do not know how to make the same model in php Lumen. So that I can just receive the model and extract the data from it. And also to use it to respond with some data (in the same JSON format) for the mobile app. Is it possible to create the model from basic classes or do they need to inherit from eloquent model? And how do I create that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'r a lot of differents questions here.
In first you want to create an API with Lumen that can receive and send JSON.
In second place, you want to convert JSON in your back-end to `Eloquent Model`.
lumen can translate your eloquent model to Json, with `Responses`.
For your main task, you will create a Controller that handle your request from mobile app , something like this :

```
class MyClassNameApi extends controller{
  public function index(CustomRequestValidator $request){
    //Do the job aka $model = new Model($request->all())
    return responses()->json($customReponse,$httpCode)  
  }
}
```

I really recommands you to check the `Requests` lifecycle of lumen.
Also don't forget to create some workflow UML to help you.

About `Model`

sample for LocOccLMouse :

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LocOCCLMouse extends Models{
   public function loc(){
     $this->hasOne(Location::class)
   }
   public function occ(){
     $this->hasOne(Occasion::class)
   } 

   public function lisMouse(){
     $this->hasMany(Mouse::class)
   }

   //Etc....
}
```

I hope i can help you

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough. I already made Controllers and I have a database. The thing is i just want to create a class or model consisting of the same properties like the class in Kotlin. So when Lumen receives request it can extract the data more easily. And if the mobile app requests data from database it will get it same format (in which it sent them to the web app).

Comment: Ok, you just need to create a classic Eloquent Model with the same attributes and relationships. It's probably the best way since you already have your database

Comment: Okay but how do I set variable type Occasion or list/array type of Mouse?

Comment: did you use foreign key in your database ? if yes , you just need to add some function in your model, you can follow the doc of laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. ,everything is explained here. I will update my answer to help you

Comment: Alright thanks I will try to figure things out. When it works I will mark the answer.

Comment: And I only need tables for Project, Session, Locality, Occasion and Mouse right? The LocOccLMouse and so on are just to help to create the final model SyncClass.

Comment: Yes, also you can create a service class for your business logic

Comment: Sorry for late response but do I need to add the attribute `protected $fillable` or create member variables in the models LocOccLMouse, SesLOLM, SyncClass in order to get or put the data in them? Or is there another way to handle the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245332/discussion-between-jumper-denfer-and-tbijo54).